# Atheros LAN card driver, Linux compiling problem

Tags: linux, opensuse, compile, linux-device-driver

I have installed openSUSE 11.4 to my new workstation.  It says that there is Attansic ETHERNET controller on board. But no devices seen. I typed: lspci and it returned: `atheros communications device 1083`. I have downloaded drivers. I'm trying to compile the driver. 
But I get the error:

```
**Makefile:94:  Linux kernel source not configured - missing autoconf.h.  Stop**
```

But I see `autoconf.h` presents on my system. What should I do ?

Comment: have you installed the kernel sources?

Comment: Yes I have installed, sources.And during installation have choosed kernel development and base development.